# Script to clear buffers / cache still says permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts

I have a script called **clearcache.sh** to clear my buffers / cache but when I run it keeps saying Permission denied.

Whats in the script: **clearcache.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sync && echo 1 | tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

---

Rights:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rt rt 464 Dec  5 02:10 clearcache.sh
```

[image]

---

How I run it to test it:

```
rt@sys76:~/clearcache$ ./clearcache.sh 
tee: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
1
```

I want to place this in a chron job but I need to get past this permission issue:

**Update:**  Here's the **drop_caches** file and it's rights owned by root what's the correct way to run this from a chron job using a script?
PS: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04

[image: image2]

Comment: What are permissions of `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`? A regular user is probably not allowed to write to that file.

Comment: @danzel it looks like root is the owner of  `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`. I add the image to the question. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Separate to everything else, there is almost never a good reason to actually do this (Linux does a solid job of managing this for you, and you're discarding performance improvement), and the rare good reasons are when you're about to run a streaming processing job, not on cron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**root & perms**

I guess you run your script with root (?)
In any way, you should not modify the access rights of the file

**no need to tee**

You dont need to `tee`, you'd better use [`sysctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/fr/man8/sysctl.8.html)

```
sudo sync && sudo sysctl vm.drop_caches=1
```

**pagecache, dentries & inodes**

```
vm.drop_caches=1 # to free pagecache
vm.drop_caches=2 # to free dentries & inodes
vm.drop_caches=3 # to free pagecache, dentries & inodes
```

So why not use `vm.drop_caches=3`

**cron schedule**

As you want to schedule it with cron, you can design your script for the root user, then schedule it by inserting a job in the root's crontab

The script

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sync
# /usr/bin/echo 1 | /usr/bin/tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
/usr/sbin/sysctl vm.drop_caches=1
```

Put the script file in a directory available to root user. For ex in the `/root` folder, ie `/root/clearcache.sh`

Then add a root cronjob
Here, the script will be run every hours, 0 minutes, every day

```
sudo crontab -e
0 * * * * /root/clearcache.sh
```

**Finally**
A script is not required, simply add the two commands as a job in the root's crontab

```
sudo crontab -e
0 * * * * /usr/bin/sync; /usr/sbin/sysctl vm.drop_caches=1
```

Comment: Thanks!.  I read an article to not use `3` in production it may cause a crash. (I was just playing it safe)  https://www.tecmint.com/clear-ram-memory-cache-buffer-and-swap-space-on-linux/

Comment: _"As sync must be run by root"_ - `sync` does not require root, so your conclusion was incorrect there.

Comment: This worked for me (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04)
`0 * * * * /bin/sync; /sbin/sysctl vm.drop_caches=1`